# Customise message.phtml pop up message magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, template-override

I want to change the **`message.phtml`** template file which renders a pop up message below on product page.

[image: Current message when options not selected]

Im not sure where in the **`KO.js`** binding message html to change
*"My new message"*

**Here is the message.phtml**

```
<?php

<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

snippet of chrome browsers ***knockoutjs context*** extension

[image: knockoutjs context, chrome extension]

**UPDATE AFTER CHANGES**

Thanks for the help...I added this to my di.xml

```
<?php

namespace  {{Vendor}}\{{Module}}\Plugin;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable; {

    class MagentoCaptchaValidation
    {
        public function afterGetSpecifyOptionMessage(Configurable $subject)
        {
            return __('Please select a size in order to place your order');
        }
    }
}
```

Error message received during the compile, why do i need this class *MagentoCaptchaValidation*

````
In PhpScanner.php line 183:
                                                                           
  Class {{Vendor}}\{{Module}}\Plugin\MagentoCaptchaValidation does not exist```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick search for that string, and this is the only place it's showing up: `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable::getSpecifyOptionMessage()`. That seems to be where the text is ultimately coming from, and you could use a plugin to change it.

---Update---

For the plugin, you would just create an `after` plugin for `getSpecifyOptionMessage()`. So, in your custom module, you'd drop this in `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable">
   <plugin name="updateOptionMessageText" type="{{Vendor}}\{{Module}}\Plugin\UpdateOptionMessage"/>
</type>
```

And this into `{{Vendor}}\{{Module}}\Plugin\UpdateOptionMessage`:

```
<?php

namespace {{Vendor}}\{{Module}}\Plugin;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable

class UpdateOptionMessage
{
    public function afterGetSpecifyOptionMessage(Configurable $subject)
    {
        return __('{{Whatever text you want}}');
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah so how do i use "a plugin to change that"?

Comment: Here are the Magento docs on that: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html 
I also edited my above comment with some more info on the plugin...

Comment: Please see my updated response

Comment: First, my apologies, I copied over a plugin that I had created, and missed changing the class name. So, you need to change the class name in `{{Vendor}}\{{Module}}\Plugin\UpdateOptionMessage` from `MagentoCaptchaValidation` to `UpdateOptionMessage`.
Second, you're getting that error because the class is not being found. The reason it isn't being found, is because of the extra set of curly brackets ({}) you have around the class. Once you remove those, and update the class name, it will work.
BTW, I updated my the code in my answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: This worked bro! thanks a lot!